# Insert and retrieve data of logged in user using firebase authentication in android

Tags: android, database, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview, firebase-authentication

I used firebase authentication to sign up and sign in users using email and password. In my application the user is saving contact information. Now I want that the data that specific logged in user entered like name and number should only be displayed in their app. Currently my application displays all the contact information in the recycler view but I want that only that data should be visible that currently logged in user entered. Here is the code of firebase authentication for registeration.

```
  mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                .addOnCompleteListener(MainActivity.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful())
                        {
                            bar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                            t1.getEditText().setText("");
                            t2.getEditText().setText("");
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Registered Successfully",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            bar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                            t1.getEditText().setText("");
                            t2.getEditText().setText("");
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Process Error",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }
                });
```

Here is the code where I'm inserting contact information

```
private void processinsert()
    {
        Map<String,Object> map=new HashMap<>();
        map.put("name",name.getText().toString());
        map.put("number",course.getText().toString());
        map.put("email",email.getText().toString());
       
        FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("contacts").push()
                .setValue(map)
                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                       name.setText("");
                       number.setText("");
                       email.setText("");
                      
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Inserted Successfully",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                })
                .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e)
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Could not insert",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });
```

This is the code of the adapter which displays the data in the recycler view.

```
public class myadapter extends FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<model,myadapter.myviewholder> {
    public myadapter(@NonNull FirebaseRecyclerOptions<model> options) {
        super(options);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final myviewholder holder, final int position, @NonNull final model model) {
       holder.name.setText(model.getName());
       holder.number.setText(model.getNumber());
       holder.email.setText(model.getEmail());
       
        holder.edit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                final DialogPlus dialogPlus=DialogPlus.newDialog(holder.img.getContext())
                        .setContentHolder(new ViewHolder(R.layout.dialogcontent))
                        .setExpanded(true,800)
                        .create();
                View myview=dialogPlus.getHolderView();
                
                final EditText name=myview.findViewById(R.id.uName);
                final EditText number=myview.findViewById(R.id.uNumber);
                final EditText email=myview.findViewById(R.id.uEmail);
                Button submit=myview.findViewById(R.id.submit);
               
                name.setText(model.getName());
                number.setText(model.getNumber());
              email.setText(model.getEmail());

                dialogPlus.show();
                submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Map<String,Object> map=new HashMap<>();
                        
                        map.put("name",name.getText().toString());
                        map.put("number",number.getText().toString());
                        map.put("email",email.getText().toString());
                        FirebaseDatabase .getInstance().getReference()
                                .child("contacts").child(getRef(position).getKey()).updateChildren(map)
                                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                                        dialogPlus.dismiss();
                                    }
                                }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                              dialogPlus.dismiss();
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
            }
        });

        holder.delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                AlertDialog.Builder builder=new AlertDialog.Builder();
                builder.setTitle("Delete Panel");
                builder.setMessage("Delete....?");
                builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        FirebaseDatabase .getInstance().getReference()
                                .child("contacts").child(getRef(position).getKey()).removeValue();
                    }
                });
                builder.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                    }
                });
                builder.show();
            }
        });
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public myviewholder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
       View view= LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.singlerow,parent,false);
       return new myviewholder(view);
    }

    class myviewholder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
    {
        
        TextView name,number,email;
        ImageView edit,delete;

        public myviewholder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

           
            name=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.nametext);
            number=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.numbertext);
            email=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.emailtext);
            edit=(ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.edit);
            delete=(ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.delete);
        }
    }
}
```

The code of MainActiviting which displays the recycler view is :

```
FirebaseRecyclerOptions<model> options=
                new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<model>()
                .setQuery(FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("contacts"),model.class)
                .build();

        myadapter=new myadapter(options);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(myadapter);
```

I read that by inserting the currently logged in user id the tree we can access the data of the currently logged in user by comparing the user id of the currently logged in user and the user id that is saved in in the tree. But I don't know how to do it exactly. Please guide me where I should insert the user_id of the currently logged in user in the tree and how to retrieve the data when that specific user is logged in.
The database structure is attached below.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a reference and set its name to the user's id and put that user's data inside it.

So instead of

```
getReference().child("contacts")
```

do

```
getReference().child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).child("contacts")
```

Answer (score 0):

So you would like to retrieve current user data, like a profile or something? You can do that using Shared Preferences. First, create a new Java class **SessionManager.java**

```
public class SessionManager {

    SharedPreferences userSessions;
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
    Context context;

    private static final String IS_LOGIN = "IsLoggedIn";
    public static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
    public static final String KEY_NUMBER= "number";
    public static final String KEY_EMAIL = "email";

    public SessionManager(Context _context) {
        context = _context;
        userSessions = _context.getSharedPreferences("userLoginSession", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        editor = userSessions.edit();
    }

    public void createLoginSession(String name, String number, String email) {    
        editor.putBoolean(IS_LOGIN, true);    
        editor.putString(KEY_NAME, name);
        editor.putString(KEY_NUMBER, number);
        editor.putString(KEY_EMAIL, email);   
        editor.commit();
    }

    public HashMap<String, String> getUsersDetailFromSession() {
        HashMap<String, String> userData = new HashMap<String, String>();
        userData.put(KEY_FULLNAME, userSessions.getString(KEY_NAME, null));
        userData.put(KEY_EMAIL, userSessions.getString(KEY_NUMBER, null));
        userData.put(KEY_EMAIL, userSessions.getString(KEY_EMAIL, null));    
        return userData;
    }

    public boolean checkLogin() {
        if (userSessions.getBoolean(IS_LOGIN, false)) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public void logoutUserSession() {
        editor.clear();
        editor.commit();
    }

}
```

Then use this code when you insert the data, to save the current user data to Shared Preferences:

```
SessionManager sessionManager = new SessionManager(getApplicationContext());
sessionManager.createLoginSession(name, number, email);
```

Use this code to retrive the data, you can put it to String variable:

```
SessionManager sessionManager = new MySharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
HashMap<String, String> hashMap = sessionManager.getUsersDetailFromSession();
String name = hashMap.get(SessionManager.KEY_NAME);
String number = hashMap.get(SessionManager.KEY_NUMBER);
String email = hashMap.get(SessionManager.KEY_EMAIL);
```

If you want to logout or clear the SharedPreferences, don't forget to call `logoutUserSession()` method

You can also check the login status by using `checkLogin()` method

Comment: I got the current user's id and saved it in the database. Just tell me a method of how to compare the current user's id with the id that is saved in database and only display those data where user id is equal to currently logged in user's id. In simple words just tell me a condition in firebase where I can compare between 2 data and if they are same so data should be retrieved.

Comment: You can try @danartillaga answer. But if you already got the user id, you can use equalTo( ) method to compare it